# Google Calendar Api works fine with local host but not with heroku in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-calendar-api

I am working on a project where we have to deploy our app to Heroku. I am using google calendar API in my project. It works perfectly fine on locally, passing through authentication and getting calendar events. But on Heroku it does not work, it just gives "if you are the application owner check the logs for more information".

Firstly I can't find the log. Secondly what could be this error about?

it just doesn't go to any authentication process, when i click the button it shows me the error to check logs

so i was able to see the logs, so this is what my log shows
[image]
my code:

```
def redirect
client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
end

def callback
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.code = params[:code]

    response = client.fetch_access_token!

    session[:authorization] = response

    redirect_to calendars_url
  end
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: May be add some screenshots of how far you are able to go on the authentication process.

Comment: As an educated guess google is applying different authentication heuristics because a login is being attempted from an unrecognized IP address. As per the other comments you need to check the logs, and possibly log more information, to see where it is failing

Comment: To check log simply use `heroku logs` to display the last 100 lines of your logs. Or to tail the logs in real-time:  `heroku logs -t`, Then please post the log in question itself.

Comment: i have updated my question, if this helps to understand the question